# Domain Access with different folders per domain

Tags: multi-sites, domain-access

I was wondering what the possibility is of having domain access run our sites and yet still have different folders per domain.  So the /sites/[domain-specific-foler] structure that is mandatory for the traditional multi-site install I want replicated for the domain access.

Is this feasible or is it not possible?  Thanks.

I am using drupal 7.x, no shared hosting.